# Variables supposed to be kept show low significance

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

Here is an interview question.

In a model, if we believe some variables should be kept. However, those variables are not significant according to the model output. What are some possible reasons?

Answer (score 6):

The list could be endless.  After vowing to stop at 20, I came up with the list below.  Many are from examples on this site; others are from my experience.  **None** are theoretical or speculative: I have seen them all.  They are in a very rough order from those worth checking first, on down.  There is some overlap, but each category is distinctive enough to be worth mentioning separately.

1. Residual variability is high.
2. Sample size is insufficiently low.
3. The model is of the wrong form entirely.
4. Collinearity.
5. Mistakes in model fitting.
6. The belief is mistaken.
7. Small effect size.
8. High measurement variability in the explanatory variables.
9. Measurement error (in response or explanatory variables).
10. Failure to sample as intended.
11. Erroneous interpretation of the output.
12. Too many variables were included.
13. Violations of implicit model assumptions, such as

    - Non-independent responses
    - Nonidentically distributed residuals
    - Residuals distributed differently than assumed
14. Overly coarse binning, discretization, or measurement of the variables.
15. Absence of crucial variables.
16. Missing data or poor data imputation.
17. Errors in recording, transcribing, or processing data.
18. Errors in applying software.
19. Software bugs.
20. Pure bad luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow #8. I wonder if you meant '*low* measurement variability' (ie, range restriction). I could also guess 'high measurement *error*', but that makes #9 superfluous.

Comment: @gung Measurement error includes systematic error.  I suppose one could include outliers in either (8) or (9).

Comment: Did you mean range restriction by 8, or the existence of outliers? Something else? I'm just not sure what that one is supposed to denote. Can it be rephrased?

Comment: @whuber Can you please explain a little more on "Residual variability is high"? How does residual variation will influence the results?

Comment: @STS, there's a lot of noise in the data.

Comment: @gung Perhaps if I wrote "measurement variance"?  "Random error"?  There is a need to distinguish errors in explanatory variables from errors in responses, because most regression models treat them asymmetrically (usually assuming the former don't even exist).

Comment: You're right about the distinction, both conceptually & in their standard treatment. Perhaps what's confusing me is that #9, which is explicitly about measurement error, states, "(in response or explanatory variables)". If 8 meant EVs & 9 meant responses, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question is about significance of individual variables in a regression model.

P-values for one variable are got from contrasting a model with that variable against a model without that variable. There are two usual reasons for a high p-value:

- The variable is not related to the response.
- The variable is related to the response but it's highly colinear with other variables. That is, the variable doesn't add more information to that of another predictor.

In first case, you could assess if it's worth keeping the variable. In the second, you may want to remove some variable and test for significance again.

Comment: It is also possible that there exists a known effect that you simply do not have power to detect. Maybe from a previous experiment you know such-and-such matters, but the effect is small. If you always throw such variables out you will (1) bias the model when you throw them out and (2) systematically over-estimate their effect when you keep them in (because, if the effect is small, the only way for you to keep it when you are underpowered is to miss high on its magnitude).

Comment: "P-value shows how significantly changes the fit of the model when just one variable is discarded."  I have no idea what that means, and I suspect it is not correct.  There are also many other reason that variables may not be significant.

Comment: I would question why they think those variables should be kept. Empirical data is stronger than "experience", and perhaps even regulation or knowledge of competitor models might have an impact, but modeling can examine those impacts properly in conjunction.